# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProssesor" not found

Tags: php, html, composer, phpword

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProssesor" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina_stps\stps\Salaries.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina_stps\stps\Salaries.php on line 13.

este es el mensaje que me aparece en la página que estoy trabajando. En sí yo estoy usando lo siguiente...

-html
-css
-php
-composer
-phpword/phpoffice

Aquí está el código tanto en php como el html:
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta name="author" content="" />
            <title>Index</title>
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest/dist/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body class="sb-nav">
            <nav class="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <!-- Navbar Brand-->
                <a class="navbar-brand ps-3" href="index.php">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <!-- Sidebar Toggle-->
                <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
                <!-- Navbar Search-->
                <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- Navbar-->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Activity Log</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="close.php">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="layoutSidenav">
                <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
                <nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-light" id="sidenavAccordion">
                        <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
                            <div class="nav">
                                <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="mainpage.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-file-alt sb-nav-link-icon"></i></div>  
                                    Acceso a la seguridad social  
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="contracts.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-marker"></i></div>
                                    Contratación
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="Rules.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i></div>
                                    Reglamento interior de trabajo
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="PrecWomenWork.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-baby-carriage"></i></div>
                                    Trabajo de mujeres en estado de gestación o periodo de lactancia
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="infWork.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></div>
                                    Trabajo de menores
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="outWork.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i></div>
                                    Trabajo de extranjeros
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-money-bill"></i></div>
                                    Salario
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="minSalaries.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-money-bill-alt"></i></div>
                                    Salario mínimo
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="workDay.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
                                    Jornada de trabajo
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="Vacations.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-plane"></i></div>
                                    Vacaciones
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="Annualty.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i></div>
                                    Aguinaldo
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="oldescalf.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i></div>
                                    Antigüedad y escalafón
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="schoolarship.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-scroll"></i></div>
                                    Otorgamiento de becas, alfabetización y fomento de actividades culturales y deportivas
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="Imss.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-ambulance"></i></div>
                                    Enteros al I.M.S.S.
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="Infonavit.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>
                                    Enteros al Infonavit
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="Infonacot.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-industry"></i></div>
                                    Enteros al Infonacot
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn-sm nav-link" href="interview.php">
                                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></div>
                                    Entrevistas
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-sidenav-footer">
                            <div class="small">Logged in as:</div>
                            Start Bootstrap
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                    <main>
                        <div class="container m-4">
                            <h1 class="mt-4">Salario</h1>
                            <div class="row">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                       
                            </div>
                            <div class="card mb-4">
                              
                                <div class="card-body">
                                   <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" class = "formulario"  method = "POST" name = "Salaries">
                                   <div class="mb-3">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3 mb-md-0">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Enter your first name" />
                                                            <label for="inputFirstName">Nombre Completo</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php if(!empty($errores)):  ?>
                                                    <div class = "errores-1">
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <?php echo $errores; ?>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <i class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick = "Salaries.submit()">Crear Cuenta</i>
                                   </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </main>
                    <footer class="py-4 bg-light mt-auto">
                        <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between small">
                                <div class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2021</div>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                                    &middot;
                                    <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="assets/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/demo/chart-bar-demo.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="js/datatables-simple-demo.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        require "views/Salaries.view.php";    
    }
    else{
        header('Location: login.php');
    }

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProssesor;

    $phptemp = new TemplateProssesor("Documents/CITDESPACHADORA.docx");
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $Nombre = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['nombre']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        if(empty($Nombre) or empty($usuario) or empty($password) or empty($password2))
        {
          $errores .= '<li>favor de llenar todos los campos correctamente</li>';
        }
        $errores = '';
        $templateVal -> setValue('Nombre', $Nombre);
        var_dump($templateVal);
    }
    ?>
```

Aquí mi duda es... ¿cómo puedo hacerlo andar? ya que no sé qué está mal en la línea 13 en el php: según el tutorial que seguí, está bien redactado.

Comment: ¿`Prossesor`? ¿ **Processor** ?

Comment: ? ... no entiendo ¿puedes elaborar a que se debe tu pregunta?

Comment: Fijate en cómo está escrito. ¿Estás seguro de que está _tipeado_ correctamente? ¿Es `Prossesor` y no `Processor`?

Comment: wow no se como se me paso eso, muchas gracias en serio, debo de estudiar mas ingles técnico y cuidar esos horrores ortográficos :////